# Errors in implementing MPI send/receive in CentOS 7

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, mpi

I am compiling this  MPI program but it is giving me 15 errors and I cannot really what the problems are. I have searched for solutions everywhere but found nothing. My code is as follows and I using CentOS 7. I am able to compile and run other examples from OPENMPI but this one is giving me errors.

```
import mpi.*;
class Hello3 {
  static public void main(String[] args) {
  MPI.Init(args) ;

 int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getRank();  
 if(myrank == 0) {
    char[] message = “Hello, there”.toCharArray();  
   MPI.COMM_WORLD.send(message, 0, message.length, MPI.CHAR, 1, 99);
 }
 else {
 char[] message = new char [20];  

 MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(message, 0, 20, MPI.CHAR, 0, 99) ;
 System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
 }
 MPI.Finalize();
}
```

If try to compile this, I get the following errors:

```
 [centos@localhost Downloads]$ mpijavac hello3.java
 hello3.java:8: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
 char[] message = “Hello, there”.toCharArray();  
            ^
 hello3.java:8: error: not a statement
 char[] message = “Hello, there”.toCharArray();  
             ^
 hello3.java:8: error: ';' expected
 char[] message = “Hello, there”.toCharArray();  
                  ^
 hello3.java:8: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
 char[] message = “Hello, there”.toCharArray();  
                         ^
  hello3.java:8: error: not a statement
  char[] message = “Hello, there”.toCharArray();  
                    ^
  hello3.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
  System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
              ^
  hello3.java:15: error: ';' expected
  System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
               ^
   hello3.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
  System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
                       ^
  hello3.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
  System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
                        ^
  hello3.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
  System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
                                                  ^
   hello3.java:15: error: not a statement
   System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
                                                ^
    hello3.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
    System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
                                                   ^
    hello3.java:15: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
     System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
                                                    ^
    hello3.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
    System.out.println(“received:” + new String(message) + “:”);
                                                     ^
     hello3.java:18: error: reached end of file while parsing
     }
      ^
     15 errors
    [centos@localhost Downloads]$
```

Is anyone able to help me please?

Comment: your source file contains some bizarre characters. `od -a hello3.java` can help you spot them. I guess it would be faster to simply rewrite this file from scratch though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have struggled resolving it. I believe the mpi methods are all okay though. Can you guide me or point to an example I can use? Thanks.

Comment: Are you now able to compile your code? If so what is the new issue?